# Нужно чтобы метод upPrice изменял price

Tags: javascript

```
let obj ={
            price: 10,
            upPrice:function (value) {
                    price += value  
            }

        }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Нужно добавить `this`, чтобы сослаться на данный экземпляр объекта:

```js
let obj = {
    price: 10,
    upPrice:function (value) {
        this.price += value  
    }
}

obj.upPrice(16);
console.log(obj.price);
```

Answer (score 0):

Забыли про `this`. Без него вы будете обращаться к локальной или глобальной переменной `price` и получать ошибку, если таковой не найдётся. `this.price` будет изменять именно поле данного объекта.

```js
let obj = {
  price: 10,
  upPrice(value) {
    this.price += value
  }
}
```